# I have a trouble getting an element from HTML page

Tags: vbscript

what I do is I navigate to a site then I want to find an element called "jobId"

```
Const PAGE_LOADED = 4

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Call objIE.Navigate("http://172.25.25.32:8090/")

objIE.Visible = True

Do Until objIE.ReadyState = PAGE_LOADED : Call WScript.Sleep(100) : Loop

objIE.Document.all.Username.Value = "ashishgi"
objIE.Document.all.Password.Value = "apac2015#"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    msgbox "Error: " & err.Description
End If

Call objIE.Document.all.gaia_loginform.submit

Set objIE = Nothing
```

when I use ViewSource this is the elements I want to use :

```
input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Login" id="logincaption" class="button" style="color:#565656"
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you're trying to click submit? Your explanation is difficult to interpret what you want the script to do. Based on the element you displayed on your sample is a submit button. It's been a while since I automated a form but I believe you want something to this effect.

```
objIE.Document.getElementsById("Username").Value = "ashishgi"
objIE.Document.getElementsById("Password").Value = "apac2015#"
' If you want to use the button by name
objIE.Document.all.item("btnsubmit").click
' If you want to use the button by ID
objIE.Document.getElementsById("logincaption").click

'if that fails, make it an object like this and action the click.
Set Submit = objIE.Document.getElementsById("logincaption")
submit.click
```

Comment: The below script works fine, but is ther a way to change the password without editing the scrip ?